# microphone fails on generic 808 webcam Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone

I have a USB "Generic WEBcam". The camera and microphone work fine when I boot this computer in Windows. In Ubuntu 20.04 the camera works fine, but the microphone does not. In the sound settings two microphones appear in the drop-down "Microphone-808 Camera" and "Multichannel Input - 808 Camera". But if I select either of them they show no input. (If I plug an old analog mic into the jack on the front of the PC, I can select that and it works fine). How can I get the microphone on the camera working?